# Python: Unable to access macro in Jinja

Tags: python, parsing, macros, jinja2

I am trying to use a macro in a jinja file.  Here is my code:

```
{{ display(class = "hello") }}

{% macro display(class) %}
    this is a macro
{% endmacro %}
```

It's pretty simple, and from what I have seen on all the examples I have seen, it should work.  However, when I go to run the program, this error occurs:

line 123, in top-level template code {{ display(class = "hello") }}

Any thoughts?

EDIT:  I originally had yaml instead of jinja in the title.  My apologies.

Comment: Show us the code that is parsing the yaml file, please.

Comment: Looking at http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html, I can't find anything about macros. Are you sure they exist in YAML?

Comment: UUUGGHH, I'm sorry guys, I meant to write in Jinja.  The same file uses both, and I was just working on the yaml a few moments ago.  Thank you @ColonelPanic for pointing that out.

Comment: Is that the entire error message? No more traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The macro must be defined or imported before you use it**.

The example on the [Jinja site](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) shows:

```
{% macro input(name, value='', type='text', size=20) -%}
    <input type="{{ type }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{
        value|e }}" size="{{ size }}">
{%- endmacro %}
```

Invoked like this after definition:

```
<p>{{ input('username') }}</p>
<p>{{ input('password', type='password') }}</p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter; those just control whether newlines are printed as far as I know. (see http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control )

Comment: Yea, I have tried using the `-%}` they just remove whitespace.

Comment: @Josh I have made changes to the answer.

Comment: Wowwww. Yep, the macro must be defined before use.  Thanks @ColonelPanic  Such a simple mistake.  Kind of embarrassed.